# Bug in modifying an element of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
const schema = new Schema({

    currentMovie: [{ lang: String, movie: String }],

});
```

and this is how it's look like in the database:

[image]

let's get the `currentMovie`  first:

```
const currentMovie = account.currentMovie.find(m => m.lang == 'en');

// below is the log of currentMovie :
{
  _id: '649944b89deb2c2fc43ffbb1',
  lang: "en",
  movie: "Zootopia 2016 - oblivion"
}
```

Now I want to modify the object which has `lang` of `'en'`:

```
const currentMovie = account.currentMovie.find(m => m.lang == 'en');

currentMovie.movie = 'Oblivion 2013';

await account.save();
```

I get this error

> account.currentMovie [ { lang: 'en', movie: 'episodic 2' } ] Error:
> Account validation failed: currentMovie: Cast to embedded failed for
> value "'Zootopia 2016'" at path "currentMovie"

This is a bug obviously but how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and the mongoose version information

Comment: mongoose version is 5

Comment: Also tried v7 (the last version) and same error..

Comment: Can you create a  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Show the minimal, complete, reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify an object from an array, you need to modify it directly because of how JavaScript keeps `object` data in the computer's memory (by reference). This is one way how that could happen:

```js
let allMovies = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    lang: "en",
    movie: "Zootopia 2016 - oblivion"
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    lang: "en",
    movie: "Another Name"
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    lang: "cv",
    movie: "the movie"
  }
];

allMovies = allMovies.map(movie => {
  if (movie.lang !== "en") return movie;
  return {
    ...movie,
    movie: "Oblivion 2013"
  };
})

console.log(allMovies);
```

In this example, you loop through the whole array and change every movie that has `lang = "en"`.

If you want to change specific movie by `id` it is better to use the following example as it it lighter and faster

```js
let allMovies = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    lang: "en",
    movie: "Zootopia 2016 - oblivion"
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    lang: "en",
    movie: "Another Name"
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    lang: "cv",
    movie: "the movie"
  }
];

allMovies[allMovies.findIndex(m => m._id === "1")].movie = "Oblivion 2013";

console.log(allMovies)
```

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question correctly ?!

Comment: The question is asking how to modify an element from an array of objects and those are the two ways that this can happen without implementing a second array or using `Map`. This is not ChatGPT, I can asure you

Comment: Looking at it again, I think I'm wrong and it probably isn't ChatGPT. I'll delete my comment. Sorry.